# Error when deploying simple Python GUI application in PyCharm, question

Tags: python-3.x, pip, pycharm

when I try to deploy application in PyCharm I receive the following error:
Where can be the problem, although I have installed all the necessary modules, I DO NOT receive the usual output GUI window?

Thanks in advance!

```
from pytube import YouTube

from kivymd.uix.relativelayout import MDRelativeLayout

from kivymd.app import MDApp

from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        layout = MDRelativeLayout()

        return layout


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

I receive the following:

```
   C:\Users\Yoan\Desktop\PythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe "C:\Users\Yoan\Desktop\PythonProject\YT Downloader.py" 
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Yoan\.kivy\logs\kivy_23-12-18_50.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.gstreamer" 0.3.3
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.3.3
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.3.1
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.6.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.2.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\Yoan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.11.2 (tags/v3.11.2:878ead1, Feb  7 2023, 16:38:35) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\Yoan\Desktop\PythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
[INFO   ] [KivyMD      ] 1.1.1, git-Unknown, 2023-12-18 (installed at "C:\Users\Yoan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\kivymd\__init__.py")
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 190 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_pil (img_sdl2, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: pil(['text_sdl2'] ignored)
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _window_sdl2: The specified module could not be found.
  File "C:\Users\Yoan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    mod = importlib.__import__(name='{2}.{0}.{1}'.format(
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1285, in __import__
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Yoan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 28, in <module>
    from kivy.core.window._window_sdl2 import _WindowSDL2Storage

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I tried to debug the program but could not find the cause, and I don't know why?